# Memetracker like visualization code

Tags: d3.js, visualization, nvd3.js

I have been searching for github repository for [Memetracker](http://www.memetracker.org/viz-elec.html) but could not find any. I also looked into [d3 streamgraph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060954) and [nvd3's stackedgraph](http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html) which look similar but have different foundations. Memetracker takes into account discontinued arrays. For example, a layer can have values from x= 5 to x = 30 and need not be continuous. While d3 and nvd3's chart assumes that there are single arrays.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is a library protovis which does that. It is not yet google searchable. http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/ex/jobs.html